# Mysql date ok but signaled as incorrect

Tags: mysql

I am trying to insert the date below into my TIMESTAMP column but it's unexpectedly signaled as incorrect format by mysql :

```
INSERT INTO `assets`( `updated_at`) VALUES ('2022-03-27 02:12:31.217573')
```

If i add or substract one day or one hour then the date is executed without error.
I going crazy ^^

Thx for your help
mysql version : 5.7.36

Answer (score 3, accepted):

timestamp columns are weird.  They effectively store a utc time, but on input and output convert to the timezone of the connection.  Presumably you are using a timezone that has daylight savings where the second after 2022-03-27 01:59:59 is 2022-03-27 03:00:00, so your entered time is invalid.

If you intend to be storing times that are already in UTC (which you should!) you need to set your timezone appropriately.  See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/time-zone-support.html.  But be aware that then all previously entered times will appear to change.

I much prefer to use datetime columns which will store and show exactly the data entered, though they have their own quirks.

Comment: Indeed, 2022-03-27 is the DST date for many countries in Europe, according to https://www.timeanddate.com/time/dst/2022.html